# DevExtreme React DataGrid resets to page 1 every time a state value changes

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, devexpress

Example Case step by step:

1. DataGrid has 5 pages, user navigates to page 3
2. User click a button (outside DataGrid component), it triggers a state changes which value doesn't even relate/connected/used by the DataGrid itself
3. DataGrid page index suddenly reset to 1

This can be frustrating and disruptive for users who are trying to navigate through large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking codes several times I found out this bug in my case happened because of conflict between `searchPanel` prop in `<DataGrid>` and `<Toolbar>` component.

So this is my code when the bug occurs:

```
<DataGrid
  {...other props}
  searchPanel={{visible: true}}
>
  <Toolbar>
    ...
  </Toolbar>
  
  ...
</DataGrid>
```

**After removing `searchPanel` prop from `<DataGrid>` and then declare Search Panel inside `<Toolbar>` component instead**, like this:

```
<DataGrid
  {...other props}
>
  <Toolbar>
    ...
    <Item name="searchPanel" visible={true} />
  </Toolbar>
  
  ...
</DataGrid>
```

**Bug gone**

I don't know exactly/technically why this pagination bug can be related to Search Panel and Toolbar. But eventually in my case, this fixed the bug.

```json
Version
"react": "^18.2.0"
"devextreme": "^22.1.6"
"devextreme-react": "^22.1.6"
```